# Delphi, cxGrid as Pie chart

Tags: delphi, charts, grid, port, pie-chart

I have to port a Delphi6 application to XE3.
But under XE3 we don't have the AdvChart components.
Because we want to use cxGrid in the future, I need some help, how to create a simple piechart with these component.
I have a DataSet with "Name" and with "Value" fields (they are % values).

The existing demos are very complex.

Could you explain the steps how to create a cxGrid which contains a piechart with these percentage values, and names in the legend (+ colorizing)?

Just for how to start it, because I'm totally confused what to do for produce something from the beginning..

Thank you for your any help, documentation, information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume the question overly broad and will vote for close, nevertheless a short example how it could be done programmatically, explaning the usual way using the IDE won't fit here.

```
var
 VIEW:TcxGridDBChartView;
 Level:TcxGridLevel;
 Series:TcxGridDBChartSeries;
begin

  View := cxGrid1.CreateView(TcxGridDBChartView) as TcxGridDBChartView;
  View.Name := 'MyChart';
  Level:=cxGrid1.Levels.Add;
  Level.GridView := View;
  View.DataController.DataSource := TheDataSource;
  View.DiagramPie.Active := true;
  Series :=View.CreateSeries;
  View.Series[0].DataBinding.FieldName := 'Value';
  View.DiagramPie.Values.CaptionPosition := pdvcpCenter;
  View.DiagramPie.Values.PercentageCaptionFormat := '0.0%';
  View.DiagramPie.Values.CaptionItems := [pdvciCategory,pdvciValue,pdvciPercentage]
end;
```